# Passing array literal as macro argument

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

This has been bugging me for some time, for example, if I'm trying to write this code:

```
// find the length of an array
#define ARRAY_LENGTH(arr) (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int))   
// declare an array together with a variable containing the array's length
#define ARRAY(name, arr) int name[] = arr; size_t name##_length = ARRAY_LENGTH(name);

int main() {
    ARRAY(myarr, {1, 2, 3});
}
```

The code gives this error:

```
<stdin>:8:31: error: macro "ARRAY" passed 4 arguments, but takes just 2
```

Because it sees `ARRAY(myarr, {1, 2, 3});` as passing `ARRAY` the argument `myarr`, `{1`, `2`, and `3}`. Is there any way to pass an *array literal* to macros?

EDIT: In some of the more complex macros I needed, I may also need to pass two or more arrays to the macro, so variadic macro does not work.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, the `{}` aren't parenthesis for the preprocessor. You can simply protect the arguments by a dummy macro

```
#define P99_PROTECT(...) __VA_ARGS__ 
ARRAY(myarr, P99_PROTECT({1, 2, 3}));
```

Should work in your case. By that you have a first level of `()` that protects the `,` from being interpreted as argument separator. These `()` of the macro call then disappear on the expansion.

See here for more sophisticated macros that do [statement unroling](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2011/03/18/statement-unrolling-with-p99_for/).

Comment: Is there any way to do this without C99 varargs?

Comment: I guess I meant something less painful, but it seems not.